# Pagination doesn't work in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a problem that i can't seem to solve. I have an index.php template and the part that shows posts goes like this:

```html
<?php
 if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 <div id="blog-masonry" class="row">
<?php
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
 endwhile; ?>
 </div><!-- .blog-masonry -->
<?php
  teletype_pagination();
 else :
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
 endif; // have_posts() ?>
```

I decided to create additional templates to show posts from specific categories, e.g.:

```html
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $your_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="blog-masonry" class="row">
    <?php query_posts('cat=4'); while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) {
        $your_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    }
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, no posts found.';
}
?>

</section><!-- #blog -->
<?php
 teletype_pagination(); 
 ?>
```

But here, the pagination doesn't work. When i click on "Go to Page 2, 3, 4", etc., it gets me to mywebsite.com/page/2, but the posts on the page remain the same.

What did i miss? Here's the teletype_pagination(); :

```html
if ( !function_exists( 'teletype_pagination' ) ) :
 function teletype_pagination() {

  // Pagination.
  the_posts_pagination( array(
     'show_all'     => False,
     'end_size'     => 1,
     'mid_size'     => 5,
     'prev_next'    => True,
     'prev_text'    => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
     'next_text'    => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
     'add_args'     => False,
     'add_fragment' => '',
     'screen_reader_text' => esc_html__( 'Posts navigation', 'teletype' ),
     'type' => 'list',
  ) );
 }
    
endif;
```

Sorry if the question is dumb, i'm a complete newbie.

UPD, Thanks for the suggestion, Suriyaa Kudo. Now the pagination works, however the state of pagination doesn't change (e.g. when i'm on page 2 or 3, "1" remains active)

Comment: Read https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105977/wordpress-pagination-not-working-always-showing-first-pages-content

Comment: Thank you! Now when i click on "2", "3", etc., the browser actually takes me to these pages. However, the state of actual pagination doesn't change, so even if i'm on, say, page 2, "1" remains active. I updated the code in my original question, please, take a look.